# PhoneGap template-based app failing to compile AdWhirl sources

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cordova, xcode4.2, adwhirl

Using Xcode4.2.1, with a basic [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) template based app. (I say template, but I cant find it now :( - PhoneGap is a static framework).

The app works ok on its own.

Now trying to add in [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/).  AdWhirl comes as source files - no library of its own, although there are libraries for the specific ad services you use.

I have added the folders to the project, but it does not seem to compile the AdWhirl sources - if amend/break the AdWhirl code, I get no compile errors.

Where I have included/imported the AdWhirl headers into my app, I had to tweak the related imports in AdWhirl files to find their dependancies - seems to be related to issue above.

I can get it compiling with that hack - but then fails to link - missing AdWhirlView, which also seems to be due to first issue - not being compiled, so not available to link.

Under build phases/compile sources, I have just 2 items: main.m and AppDelegate.m - do I need to add the AdWhirl code into here?

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/kimptoc/Sample-AdWhirl-Xcode4-project) with just the AdWhirl stuff, no PhoneGap, but still has the issue :(

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers.

Comment: How is AdWhirl distributed? Is it a static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to post the answer here that I gave on Twitter. Seems like the issue is that Xcode is unhappy with folder references. Try reimporting the AdWhirl files into your project, but tell Xcode to add groups for folders, rather than folder references. (Incidentally, if anyone knows why Xcode is choking on the folder references, I'd love to hear about it.)

Then, you'll start getting errors about ARC and missing files pertaining to the Google Ads framework. So, you'll have to add the Google Ads files to quell the errors; then, you'll want to make sure ARC is disabled in your project. If you want to use ARC, then your best bet is to repackage AdWhirl as a static library that builds without ARC, and have that as a dependency in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks Jon, after re-adding as groups, I noticed under the "Compile Sources" config, it has all the AdWhirl files listed now - so I possibly could have added all 44 files manually that way... :).